# Is there any way to make this CRTP work with inheritance?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20

Pardon the *very* vague question but I am struggling with even finding the proper words to describe what I'm trying to do. Basically, when I write a class I like having:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    using uptr = std::unique_ptr<A>;
    using sptr = std::shared_ptr<A>;
    using wptr = std::weak_ptr<A>;

};
```

So I can use `A::uptr` and such.

Now I am starting to have a lot of classes with this mechanism and I was wondering if it was posssible to generalize it, somehow like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Ptrs
{
public:
    using uptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
    using sptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    using wptr = std::weak_ptr<T>;
};

class A : public Ptrs<A>
{
};
```

This seems to work properly but as soon as I introduce inheritance, it breaks. For example:

```cpp
class B : public A
{
};

B::uptr b; // this is a unique_ptr<A>

class B : public Ptrs<B>, public A // does not compile
{
};
```

So I was wondering if there was any way to do this. I am using C++20, I am just not very familiar with templates / concepts / SFINAE and such. I am also not sure if this is even a good idea, I just thought it would be nice to have a way to do this.

Comment: In the second case, do you want `B::uptr` to be `std::unique_ptr<B>` ? Can you share the reason why you need this?

Comment: Ok I'm a bit confused now. Do I not need it? What happens when pass sptrs I std::move uptrs around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you derive `B` from both `Ptrs<B>` and `A` you're introducing two sets of identical type aliases. Therefore, the compiler is not able to figure out which one you want.

The use of the CRTP cannot help you here. However, it's opposite pattern, mixins, may help you. Mixins are small classes that are intended to add common functionality to (unrelated) classes. Instead of deriving `A` and `B` from `Ptrs`, you derive `Ptrs` from `A` or `B`. Here is an example:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Ptrs : public T
{
public:
   using uptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
   using sptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
   using wptr = std::weak_ptr<T>;
};

class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};

int main()
{
    Ptrs<A>::uptr a;
    Ptrs<B>::uptr b;
}
```

I don't know if this suites your need but this is the closest I can find.

Comment: `Ptrs<A>::uptr` is not that much different from `unique_ptr<A>`.

Comment: I've head of mixins from Ruby and never quite got them. Its cool to see how they could be used in C++

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I agree. I don't think it brings much benefit. The only reason for posting it is demonstrating what's possible. Personally, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I see. I guess I'll go back to the old ways. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this if you turn things around on their head a bit.

```
template <class Base, class Derived> 
struct Ptrs : public Base {
  using uptr = std::unique_ptr<Derived>;
  // etc
};

 struct None {};

 class A : public Ptrs<None, A> {};

 class B : public Ptrs<A, B> {};
```

This is not pretty because the inheritance structure is not obvious, but it works for the most part (warning: specifically the above code is untested).